# Auto fill form field in html with data value and make it read only

Tags: python, django

I'm in process of creating a page where you can add a customer with some information regarding to them. I want to assign an unique id for each customer. I of course type in the basic information myself, but I also need a field in the form that has been populated with a generated random id, that has been checked in the database if it already exists. If it doesn't then fill it into the form, and if it does then generate a new one until a not used one is found.

Models.py

```
class Opretkunde(models.Model):
    Fornavn = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Efternavn = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Telefon = models.IntegerField()
    Adresse = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Postnummer = models.IntegerField()
    IA = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    salgsperson = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="missing")
```

The field IA is the field which should be automatically populated with the randomly generated value

forms.py

```
class Opret_kunde_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Opretkunde
        fields = ['Fornavn', 'Efternavn', 'Telefon', 'Adresse', 'Postnummer', 'IA']
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = Opret_kunde_form(request.POST, request.FILES) 
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False) 
            instance.salgsperson = request.user 
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('createUser:createUser'))
    else:
        form = Opret_kunde_form()
    return render(request, 'createCustomer.html', {'form': form})
```

The function im using to generate a value looks like this

```
def random_with_N_digits(n):
    range_start = 10**(n-1)
    range_end = (10**n)-1
    return randint(range_start, range_end)
```

I'm thinking of something that could look like this

```
Uniquevalue = random_with_N_digits(8)
If Uniquevalue Opretkunde.objects.filter(IA=Uniquevalue).exists()
   generate new uniquevalue
   check again and if it doesnt exist then insert to form
```

Comment: Umm, if you're using the ORM approach, why aren't you using the auto-incrementing user id instead of generating random numbers?

Comment: I'm no expert at programming, so i'm not sure what you mean. I'm not really sure what the ORM approach is. Care to elaborate for a noob? :-)

Comment: You presumably have a table for users? I don't use django, but flask, so I could be well off. The ORM (object relational mapper) should map a User class to your database and they'll get assigned a User ID. In other words, your users should already have a unique id

Comment: I think I understand now. The thing is I don't need a unique ID from my users or a way to populate it that way. The function I added into my question is really just a template right now. I need a more specific ID with a prefix of my own, but I can do that myself. I just need to know how to auto populate the field with some data to start of with.